# Python: Operandtype-Error in a method, but not in main, with the same code

Tags: python, list, class

im new in programming with python and tried to make a own vector class. This class has a variable values, which is a list of integer values. The constructor looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args: int):
    if len(args) == 0: self.values = [0, 0]
    else: self.values = [value for value in args]
```

I wanted to implement a method, called "vector_sum" which is a static method and shall return a Vector with the values of the sum of the corresponding elements. For example (just the calculation):
sum((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))=(9,12)

My method looks like this:

```
def vector_sum(vectors: List[Vector]) -> Vector:
        vals: List[int] = []
        for i in range(len(vectors)):
            for j in range(len(vectors[i].values)):
                if i == 0:
                    vals.append(vectors[i].values[j])
                else:
                    vals[j] += vectors[i].values[j]
        z: Vector = Vector(*vals)
        return z
```

When i want to print the result of the method there is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 61, in <module>
    print(sum(vectors).values)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Vector'
```

I am very confused, because if i try to run this exact same code via main, it works just fine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    v: Vector = Vector(1, 2)
    w: Vector = Vector(3, 4)
    x: Vector = Vector(5, 6)
    vectors: List[Vector] = [v, w, x]
    vals: List[int] = []
    for i in range(len(vectors)):
        for j in range(len(vectors[i].values)):
            if i == 0:
                vals.append(vectors[i].values[j])
            else:
                vals[j] += vectors[i].values[j]
    z: Vector = Vector(*vals)
    print(z.values)
```

This prints out following result:

```
[9, 12]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can not explain why this happens. It's so confusing, that it runs in main but not in the method, although it is the exact same code.

PS: Of course i use the list "vectors" for both scenarios.

It would be nice if you could help me.
Greetings Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `vector_sum`, the function you created, rather than `sum`:

```
print(vector_sum(vectors).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` takes a second, optional argument to specify the initial value. If you don't supply it, it defaults to `0` rather than assuming the iterable argument is empty. That's why `sum([]) == 0` and `sum([1]) == 1 + 0 == 1`. Basically, `sum` behaves like

```
def sum(itr, init=0):
    rv = init
    for x in itr:
        rv += x
    return rv
```

The initial value should be the identify for the actual addition operator. `0` works fine for numbers, since `x + 0 == 0 + x == x` for numeric types. It does *not* work for your vectors, because you haven't specified what `v + 0` means. You need to do that, or provide an identity vector as the second argument to `sum`.

(All this assumes you have defined `Vector.__add__` to allow `sum` to add vectors *at all*.)